# I am trying to transform the file name (TM_FILENAME_BASE) but remove a key word from the middle of the text

Tags: regex, vscode-snippets

For example I have a file named 'prefix-component.suffix.ts'. I would like the result to be PrefixSuffix with the word 'component' removed. I can make this work by using `${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*?)\\bcomponent\\b(.*)/${1:/pascalcase}${2:/pascalcase}/g}`. `${1:/pascalcase}` is everything before 'component' and `${2:/pascalcase}` is everthing after. The problem is not all file names have the word 'component' in them so group 1 and 2 are empty in those cases. Is there a way to do this with 1 `${1:/pascalcase}` with 'component' removed if it is present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `\bcomponent\b` and the suffix collectively optional:

```
${
  TM_FILENAME_BASE
  /
    ^                             # Match at the start of the string
    (.*?)                         # anything, as few as possible,
    (?:                           # until we see
      (?:\bcomponent\b)           # 'component' as a full word
      (.*)                        # followed by anything,
    )?                            # both of which may or may not collectively present
    $                             # right before the end of the string.
  /
    ${1:/pascalcase}
    ${2:/pascalcase}
  /g
}
```

| Before | Prefix | Suffix | After |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `prefix-component.suffix` | `prefix-` | `.suffix` | `PrefixSuffix` |
| `prefix.suffix` | `prefix.suffix` | Nothing | `PrefixSuffix` |

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rbz9j6/1).